# Symfony Many-to-many query

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I have a question about Symfony's Many-to-many relationships. I have a query, that tries to get all the fields of an entity (outside this part), and on top of that query, it adds the following:

```
 $queryBuilder
            ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Location', 'location',
                Join::WITH, 'location.id IN (entity.locations)')
            ->andWhere('location.institute=:institute')
            ->setParameter('institute', $user->getInstitute());
```

On that entity, a Many-to-many relationship is present: entity has a m2m relationship with location. Now I try to get all entities that have the same institute as the user has.
So I query the locations, and check if the institute of the locations have the same institute.

However, I then get

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 118: Error: Expected Literal, got 'entity'

What should I be doing different? I understand it goes wrong with the `IN` part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `entity.locations` is a variable.

If so, you need to add `:` in front of and `setParameter` as well.

Change your code to:

```php
$queryBuilder
  ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Location', 'location', Join::WITH, 'location.id IN (:locations)')
  ->setParameter('locations', entity.locations);
  ->andWhere('location.institute=:institute')
  ->setParameter('institute', $user->getInstitute());
```

Please let me know if this solve your issue, thanks!

Comment: I think I did not yet give enough information. Entity is the selection in the query, i.e. the data I want to retrieve. This is done within an entity type for Symfony.

I have an Entity called subjects, which has the many to many relation with location. This is what entity is referring to, the subjects that is retrieved using the query.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found out that the answer is as follows:

```
 $queryBuilder
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Location', 'location',
            Join::WITH, 'location MEMBER OF entity.locations')
        ->andWhere('location.institute=:institute')
        ->setParameter('institute', $user->getInstitute());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).